# Show/Hide Back Button in Toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I want to show back button in toolbar under some circumstances, and hide it under another. I wrote below code:

```
public void setupToolbar() {
    if (mStacks.get(mCurrentTab).size() > 1) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(v -> onBackPressed());
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

But my problem is when I set home button as false, It won't be visible anymore even the first condition becomes true. Can anybody help me?

Comment: try to call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`

Comment: @AtefHares Nothing changed.

Comment: Are you setting your toolbar as your support action bar? You're required to do this in your onCreate() method:  
                                                      
 // toolbar
    `Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi Yes, I set it as support action bar.

Answer (score 10):

Show/Hide Back Button in Toolbar. please try it

show code

```
 if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }
```

and hide code

```
 if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood your point correctly you should use below codes:

```
 private void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive mode.
    // For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
    // Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                    // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
                    // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    // Hide the nav bar and status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

this function hides BackButton and HomeButton

for show you should use below codes:

```
private void showSystemUI() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```